# Allow users to configure notified email addresses

Tags: gitolite

I want my users to be able to subscribe new commit notifications. Subscriptions should be per gitolite repository, and the user shouldn't have to contact me every time they want to add a subscription or project. Is there a hook which allows that?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a post-receive hook to send commit messages to a mailing list (per-project, managed by [majordomo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majordomo_%28software%29) or similiar) and let people subscribe/unsubscribe to the list?

Then all you have to do is create the per-project mailing lists once and let the software deal with the rest.

Comment: This sounds prone to breakage. But more importantly, my users can also setup their own repositories, so I'd have to allow/teach them to create a mailing list as well.

Comment: There are plenty of majordomo front-ends that let users create their own mailing lists (or you could make your users use a repo-creating script that also creates the mailing list). Routing the commit messages to a battle-proven mailing list system is how every major source-hosting project I'm aware of (and every decently managed company) solves this problem, and I'd wager it's less prone to breakage than trying to home-grow your own system. Mailing lists are a solved problem, you're almost certainly better off using that solution [trying to reinvent the wheel](http://vimeo.com/2997888).